# Expand the series and find the summation.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}$

find $f(2x+1)$

Is this the correct expansion

> $f(2x+1)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\sum_{i=1}^k{k\choose i}(2x)^i$
>
> **Is it possible to do the following step**:
>   [image]

Comment: Yes, but lower bound for $i$ is $0$, not $1$ (and for $k$ too)

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I didn't understand, how the $f(2k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\sum_{i=1}^k{k\choose i}(2k)^i$ is written. Can you provide me the proof or anything ?

Comment: He means:
$$f(2k+1)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}(2k)^i$$

Comment: You just changed variables. $f(1+2x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (1 + 2x)^k$. By Newton, $(1+2x)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}(2x)^i$. So,
$$
f(1+2x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}(2x)^i
$$

Comment: @Tolaso I understand that for sure. But how is it obtained like,
$f(2x+1)=a_0+a_1(2x+1)+a_2(2x+1)+\dots+a_n(2x+1)^n$ how come this be equal to two summands like $f(2k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}(2k)^i$

Comment: @HeinzKloube In the last formula of your last comment $2k+1$ serves as argument on LHS and $k$ serves as index on RHS. That is not kosher and causes confusion.

Comment: No. Again $k$ cannot serve as index and argument in the same expression.

Comment: @drhab can I write $f\left(2x+1\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\left(2x+1\right)^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(2x\right)^{i}1^{k-i}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(2x\right)^{i}$=$2N+\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$

Comment: If $x$ is an integer then indeed you can conclude that $f(2x+1)-a_0-\cdots-a_n$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not clear to me, but I thought you might want to have a polynomial in $x$ for example of the form $$f(2x+1)=\sum_{i=0}^nb_ix^i.$$ If this is the case then proceed as follows:

\begin{align}
f(2x+1)&=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}(2x)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i}^na_k{k\choose i}(2x)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\Big[2^i\sum_{k=i}^na_k{k\choose i}\Big]x^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nb_ix^i\\
\end{align}
where $b_i=2^i\sum_{k=i}^na_k{k\choose i}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Binomial Theorem states: $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$

Applying this to your problem gives
$f(2x+1) = \sum_{k=0}^na_k(2x+1)^k = \sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(2x)^{k-i}1^i = \sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(2x)^i1^{k-i}$ (the last expression follows from the previous one by symmetry of the summands in the argument, as addition is commutative).

Of course, you needn't bother writing the "$1^i$" or "$1^{k-i}$" bits; those just there for demonstration, to show clearly how the Binomial Theorem is applied.

Answer (score 1):

On base of $\left(a+b\right)^{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}a^{i}b^{k-i}$
we find:

$f\left(2x+1\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\left(2x+1\right)^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(2x\right)^{i}1^{k-i}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(2x\right)^{i}$

You could go further to achieve:

$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^{i}a_{k}\binom{k}{i}x^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{k=i}^{n}2^{i}a_{k}\binom{k}{i}x^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_{i}x^{i}$
where $b_{i}=2^{i}\sum_{k=i}^{n}a_{k}\binom{k}{i}$

Comment: I also posted something similar :-)